# Create a new table using two existing tables based on unique id column

Tags: mysql, join

Probably this is stupid but I am trying to create a new table in my database by joining two existing tables that both have product_ID as primary and unique.

I tried this but didn't work

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_name
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2, WHERE t1.product_id = t2.product_id;

CREATE TABLE new_table_name
SELECT *
FROM table1 AS t1, table2 AS t2, WHERE t1.product_id = t2.product_id;
```

Comment: You wouldn't be able to use *, i.e. you would have list out all the columns.

Comment: and the reason is that you have columns with the same name in both tables such as product_Id, the system doesn't know what to call the second product_ID table.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the sytax is wrong may be you should try this

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
AS (SELECT * FROM old_table);


CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE
AS
  (SELECT *
FROM table1 AS t1, table2 AS t2, WHERE t1.product_id = t2.product_id);
```

Comment: I tried listing the columns but doesn't work

`CREATE TABLE new_table_name
SELECT product_id, name, stock
FROM table1 AS t1, table2 AS t2, WHERE t1.product_id = t2.product_id;`

stock is from the second table, t2

Both of the above syntax also doesn't work.
I get syntax error near WHERE.

Will keep trying

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have AS and that the column names in the new tables are all unique column names - Example:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (ID INT, TXT VARCHAR(20));
CREATE TABLE T2 (ID INT);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (1, '1111');
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (3, '3333');
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (3);
CREATE TABLE T3 AS (SELECT A.ID, A.TXT, B.ID AS "NewNameForID" FROM T1 A, T2 B WHERE A.ID=B.ID)
```

Note here that B.ID was renamed using AS to make all column names in the resulting table unique.

The resulting table T3 would be a table with columns: ID, TXT, NewNameForID and 1 row.

Please adapt to your tables.

Answer (score 0):

Use CREATE TABLE ... SELECT syntax.

See this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html